# SQLalchemy - Login with SQL server authentication

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am using SQLalchemy with pyodbc to connect to a SQL server. I can connect using "Windows Authentication":

```
create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://[ServerName]/[DatabaseName]',echo=True)
```

That is fine but when I try to login (SQL server authentication) it fails:

```
create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://[User]:{Password]@[ServerName]/[DatabaseName]',echo=True)
```

1. Is my code correct? Am I missing a setting?
2. Is there a way of listing database users to check the names?

Comment: Please provide the error message received when using SQL Server auth, will give us a better idea of what is needed to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, your connection string is correct. Make sure the user/pwd combinations are correct. Also note that user/pwd can only be used for users which use "SQL Server authentication" (in the code below `SQL_LOGIN`) and not "Windows authentication"
2. Given you connect with enough permissions, you can execute the following to see all logins:
   `for x in session.execute("SELECT name, type, type_desc FROM sys.server_principals"):
       print x`